# Django session keyerror, how to conserve the state of django session between to http cross-origin request from angular to django

Tags: python, django, angular

I have an angular frontend app which send file to django backend which data is setting in django session. After I send a httprequest to django backend to make ML tratements on that data and get the results. But I've a 500 sever error: keyerror 'ts_dataset_copy': KeyError: 'ts_dataset_copy'
[24/Feb/2020 18:43:46] "GET /cv_classification/5/FOTS/283/None/0/0 HTTP/1.1" 500 78264. Here are my django code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_local_dataset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dataset = pd.read_csv(request.FILES.get('datasetfilepath'), header=None, index_col=None)
        request.session['ts_datset'] = dataset.to_json(orient='values')
        request.session['ts_dataset_copy'] = dataset.to_json(orient='values')
        print("In upload_local_dataset Session's keys : ", request.session.keys())

        return HttpResponse(dataset.to_json(orient='values'))
```

## second httrequest that throws a server internal error

```
def cv_classification(request, kfolds, dissimilarity_func, windows_length=0, noisy_law="", mu=0, 
    std=0):
        noisy_law = noisy_law.lower()
        print("In cv_classification Session's keys : ", request.session.keys())
        df = pd.read_json(request.get('ts_dataset_copy'), orient='values')
        predictions = cv_classify(df, kfolds, dissimilarity_func, windows_length, noisy_law, mu, std)
        return JsonResponse(predictions, safe=False)
```

The matter is that when I send the second http crosss-origin from angular app to my django app the previously session's elements that I've stored doesn't exist anymore. (I checked the session keys in the upload_local_dataset and receive ***In upload_local_dataset Session's keys :  dict_keys(['ts_dataset', 'ts_dataset_copy'])*** but in the second views I received an empty dict ***In cv_classification Session's keys :  dict_keys([])*** so pandas' read_json throws an error ***ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:***

How can I save the state of session between two http cross-origin from angular app to django app ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will have to handle the case that the key is not present in the session yet.

Comment: When I call the second view method, the key has been already created by the first method upload_local_dataset()

Comment: Obviously that is just your expectation.